# List all users using Drupal Views

Tags: entities, views

I am new to Drupal and Views. I need to list all the authors(users) in my drupal 7 page? Do I need to add relationships for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

When you add a new View, in the first screen there is a GUI with menus that let you create a view to;

```
Show users sorted by newest first
```

And that is all there is to it!

You can obviously refine the View to enhance the presentation, change the sorting, add a pager, etc. - but just to list the users, the above is what is required.